# Autofill formula in defined column VBA

Tags: excel, vba, autofill

I'm trying to autofill a formula in a defined column, but I'm having problems. So far I have found the last column, pasted the formula in row 2 of that column, but I can't get it to autofill down (based on the rows filled in column A). Any Advice?

```
Sub paste_Formula()

Dim emptycolumn As Long

Dim destination2 As Worksheet

Set destination2 = Sheets("Sheet1")

With Worksheets("sheet1")

    usedRows1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

emptycolumn = destination2.Cells(1, destination2.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
If emptycolumn > 1 Then
    emptycolumn = emptycolumn + 1
End If

destination2.Cells(1, emptycolumn).Value = "Formula"
    destination2.Cells(2, emptycolumn).Value = "=L2&M2"

With (.Cells(2, emptycolumn))
    .AutoFill destination:=Range(usedRows1, emptycolumn), Type:=xlFillDefault   **this is where I get  runtime error 1004**

End With
End with
End Sub
```

Comment: `Destination` must include the source range. [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.autofill) You're also using `Cells` syntax for `Range` and using an implicit reference. You want `.Range(.cells(2, emptycolumn),.cells(usedrows1, emptycolumn))` removing the inner `With` statement so you can use the outer one on that line.

Comment: Skip the autofill, and write the formula to the entire range in one go. `.Range(.cells(2, emptycolumn),.cells(usedrows1, emptycolumn)).Formula = "=L2&M2"`